# Method Range of Object Worksheet Failed While I Trying to Copy A range to another range

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy a range to another sheets range but I failed. Always its getting Method range of object worksheet failed error code. Here is my code

Error Line is = addtc_copy.Range("B:AP" & x).Copy Destination:=db.Range("B:AP" & mylastrow_db)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub adddatabase()

Dim addtc_copy As Worksheet
Dim mylastrow_tc As Long
Dim mylastrow_db As Long
Dim db As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer

Set addtc_copy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ADD_TC")
Set db = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATABASE")

mylastrow_tc = addtc_copy.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
mylastrow_db = db.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

x = 2
Do Until x > mylastrow_tc

   addtc_copy.Range("B:AP" & x).Copy Destination:=db.Range("B:AP" & mylastrow_db)

   mylastrow_db = mylastrow_db + 1
   x = x + 1
Loop

MsgBox "ALL CARDS HAVE BEEN ADDED TO DATA BASE"

End Sub
```

Comment: Please format your code properly with the {} button in the menu when editing your question (you have to select the code first)(ty Ike). Aside from that, where's the start of your range? `Range("D" & mylastrow_db` is valid, `Range("D:E" & mylastrow_db)` isn't since it needs a start, i.e. `Range("D1:E" & mylastrow_db)` or `.Range("B" & x & ":P" & x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying each row one at a time, where there doesn't appear to be a need. Simply copy the block across, defined by row 2 to `mylastrow_tc`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub adddatabase()
    
    Dim addtc_copy As Worksheet
    Dim mylastrow_tc As Long
    Dim mylastrow_db As Long
    Dim db As Worksheet
    
    Set addtc_copy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ADD_TC")
    Set db = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATABASE")
    
    mylastrow_tc = addtc_copy.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    mylastrow_db = db.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    addtc_copy.Range("B2:AP" & mylastrow_tc).Copy Destination:=db.Range("B" & mylastrow_db)
    
    MsgBox "ALL CARDS HAVE BEEN ADDED TO DATA BASE"

End Sub
```